# NewRelic and Ajax Requests from Kendo Grid datasource refresh

Tags: ajax, kendo-grid, newrelic

I have a scenario in which a Kendo Grid is loaded with data.  The user then clicks a Refresh data button, which causes the Grid's datasource to execute its Read operation, executing an ajax request that returns json data, which is used to refresh the content of the grid.

My question is, does this ajax request appear in any NewRelic measures/dashboard views?

Answer (score 0):

they do, but you need a pro licence:
http://newrelic.com/browser-monitoring/pricing